# Export results from postman such that they can be viewed using tool other than postman(e.g browser, csv)

Tags: postman

I am currently testing APIs used in my tool using Postman Collections. I am able to see the current & previous results in the Recent Runs section. However there is no way to track this or export this outside postman. I would like to be able to export these results in a format such that another person without Postman can also view the results (say in a browser).

I have been using newman and the export feature in Newman which allows me to export the test results in a csv or html format.However I would like to know if such feature exists in Postman. Also where would I be able to find the program data for Postman in case I need to write a custom reporting module.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no Feature like this in newman.
But: In Postman Runner you can export your results in a JSON Format. And In the Postman Client you can save your responses if needed.